# Flowchart nodes permitted in any order?

Tags: flowchart

I'm writing the instructions for a process. Steps C, D, and E must be done between Step B and Step F, but they can be done in any order. What's the best way to show that in a flowchart?

In what I hope is a related question: If Step X can be performed *at any point* between Step F and Step K, how would I signify that on a flowchart?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm writing the instructions for a process. Steps C, D, and E must be done between Step B and Step F, but they can be done in any order. What's the best way to show that in a flowchart?

The *best way* is up to you. There are *different ways*, some are easier to program--others are easier to explain. And, while you only ask about process; there is, at least, *some* similarity between programming a computer and instructing others.

The first diagram shows the various routes that may be taken. These routes are presented using something like a state diagram, without noting the context of the transitions. The context required is *next*; that is, *I did this--what's next*.. There are six combinations each with four paths, to cover all possibilities.

[image: State Machine Diagram]

Although I used simple *process* symbols in the following; any could need a *predefined process* symbol, if they are (or could be) diagrammed with a separate flowchart.

The second diagram has two implementation choices. (Using C psuedocode to explain.)

[image: Flowchart]

Using a `for` statement,

```
int next[3]; // next is prepared elsewhere, 
             // because each next[] value is unique there can be no repetition
{
    b();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        case 1: c();
        case 2: d();
        case 3: e();
    }
    f();
}
```

Or, for old time state machine people, using `goto` statements (Note that `goto` is often used in instructions for US income tax forms and may be useful for instructing others, in other contexts.)

```
int next[4]; // next is prepared elsewhere, next[3] defaults to 4 or F
int i = 0;
{
    b();
    switch (next[i++])
    {
        case 1: goto C;
        case 2: goto D;
        case 3: goto E;
        default: goto F;
    }
C:  c(); // do the C thing
    switch (next[i++])
    {
        case 1: goto C;
        case 2: goto D;
        case 3: goto E;
        default: goto F;
    }
D:  d(); // do the D thing
    switch (next[i++])
    {
        case 1: goto C;
        case 2: goto D;
        case 3: goto E;
        default: goto F;
    }
E:  e(); // do the E thing
    switch (next[i++])
    {
        case 1: goto C;
        case 2: goto D;
        case 3: goto E;
        default: goto F;
    }
F:  f();
}
```

The third diagram uses nested `if` statements,

[image: Flowchart]

```
int next[3]; // next is prepared elsewhere, next[3] is not used
{
    b();
    if (next[0] == 1)
    { 
        c();
        if (next[1] == 2)
        {
            d();
            e();
        }
        else
        {
            e();
            d();
        }
    }
    else if (next[0]) == 2)
    {
        d();
        if (next[1] == 1)
        {
            c();
            e();
        }
        else
        {
            e();
            c();
        }
    }
    else if (next[0] == 3)
    {
        e();
        if (next[1] == 1)
        {
            c();
            d();
        }
        else
        {
            d();
            c();
        }
    }
    f();
}
```

The fourth diagram uses a `switch` statement for the required pattern,

[image: Flowchart]

```
int pattern; // prepared elsewhere, values 1 through 6
{
    b();
    switch (pattern)
    { 
        case 1:
        {
            c();
            d();
            e();
        }
        case 2:
        {
            c();
            e();
            d();
        }
        case 3:
        {
            d();
            c();
            e();
        }
        case 4:
        {
            d();
            e();
            c();
        }
        case 5:
        {
            e();
            c();
            d();
        }
        case 6:
        {
            e();
            d();
            c();
        }
    }
    f();
}
```

---

> In what I hope is a related question: If Step X can be performed at any point between Step F and Step K, how would I signify that on a flowchart?

[image]

```
{
    f();
    if (condition) x();
    g();
    if (condition) x();
    h();
    if (condition) x();
    i();
    if (condition) x();
    j();
    if (condition) x();
    k();
}
```